# HTML and PHP Multiple Checkboxes Form handling

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to create a bus seat booking system. As you can see from the image below, there are 30 seats with 3 column. Currently after clicking the submit button, my code (can see example code below) will display the seat number that they have chosen. But what I want to add is to display the seat type and price, ok for example (from the image):

- Left column type of seat is 'single', middle column is 'aisle', and right column is 'window'.
- 'single' seat is $10 while the others are $5.

So, how do I display the seat number with its type and price in efficient way? (maybe using multidimensional array?). Sorry if my question is not clear enough as I'm still beginner in coding.

[bus seat booking system (click here to see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAzxx.png)

**my html (3 seat example):**

```
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="1" id="1"/>
          <label for="1"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="2" id="2"/>
          <label for="2"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="3" id="3"/>
          <label for="3"></label>
        </li>
```

**my php:**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
  if(!empty($_POST["seatcheckbox"]))
  {
    echo 'You have selected the following seats: ';
    foreach($_POST["seatcheckbox"] as $seatcheckbox)
    {
      echo $seatcheckbox . ', ';
    }
  }
  else {
    {
      echo 'Please select at least 1 seat';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not included the HTML code for price

Comment: @NadirLatif I have yet to do it. I mean, I want different price for single seat ($10) and others ($5). How do I assign it and output it corresponding with the user's seat selection?

Comment: Please include the HTML code

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to do it, for simplicity since I haven't seen your HTML implementation you can experiment with this:

```
<?php
 for( $i = 0; $i <= 30 ; $i++){
      if( ( ($i+3) % 3) == 0){
           echo "single price";
        }else{
           echo "double price";
      }
 }
?>
```

Comment: this looks promising, I will try it later. Thank you!